# Make SSH agent to confirm the passphrase with interval (AddKeysToAgent confirm interval example)

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, passphrase

Right now, the system is asking me for the SSH key passphrase only once during the session. However, I don't find it secure and I would like it to ask me for the password periodically (e.g. every 10 minutes).

According to the man pages, the `AddKeysToAgent` option supports this behavior, however, I can't find a working example of such config and the specification is not very clear.

Can I have an example of such configuration, please?

Comment: Having the same issue. Be great to see an answer for this. Setting `AddKeysToAgent 600` generates an error. But setting `AddKeysToAgent yes` works as expected.